# How do I know the gzip compression level?

Tags: linux, compression, gzip

Given a gzip compressed file, how do I know what compression level (1-9) was used for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to directly determine gzip level .
The only way to determine it in my opinion is to gunzip the file and  compressing it at different levels and then  comparing the results with your existing file size.
I believe the default level is 6 so in most cases that should be your answer

Comment: I read somewhere that tar -cz defaults to 9. Is that true?

Comment: Yes. GNU tar uses level 9 by default when gzipping.

Comment: Python also defaults to a compression level on 9: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html

Comment: Is it in the tar source or documented somewhere that -9 is the default?

Comment: nginx defaults to level 1 by the way. https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_comp_level

Comment: @AndrewLambert Source for that information? I tried GNU tar 1.34 on Debian Bookworm and in the git shell for Windows. Both default to -6. Also confirmed by https://superuser.com/a/305134/165722

Answer (score 34):

It is stored in the header of file. To see it, use `file` command. For example:

```
$ file testfile.gz
testfile.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Sun Sep 15 14:22:19 2013, max compression
```

Unfortunately there are only three possible values in the header: max speed (level 1), max compression (level 9) and "normal" (all other levels). But better than nothing!

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: Looks like the rest of a compressed file isn't any clearer. Test-compressing a 201 bytes file with all levels resulted in only 4 different outputs - partitioned by levels as (1,23,45678,9) - with levels 1 and 9 specifically marked (see XFL in RFC1952; that's why `file` can recognise those). A 10^7 bytes file still only resulted in 7 unique outputs - partitioned (1,2,3,4,5678,9). While this doesn't mean different levels are useless for bigger files, it shows you can't assume 9 unique outputs.

Comment: Every version of Python until 3.5 (maybe even including 3.6) sets the compression level in the header to 9 even when it is not.  Just a bug, but FYI: https://bugs.python.org/issue27521

Comment: For me `file` only shows `gzip compressed data`.

Answer (score 7):

`gzip -l <filename>` will give you the compression ratio, but there's no way of directly finding the compression level used.

Comment: While the assertion about elvel is false, the command is useful for comrpession ratio.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way of knowing it. It most probably 6 (the current default) or 9 (the best compression). you need to try and compare.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153334/how-to-determine-the-compression-level-of-deflate