# How to specify level of compression when using tar -zcvf?

Tags: linux, compression, tar, gzip

I gzip directories very often at work. What I normally do is

```
tar -zcvf file.tar.gz /path/to/directory
```

Is there a way to specify the compression level here? I want to use the best compression possible even if it takes more time to compress.

Answer (score 211):

```
GZIP=-9 tar cvzf file.tar.gz /path/to/directory
```

assuming you're using bash. Generally, set [`GZIP` environment variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/manual/html_node/Environment.html) to "-9", and run tar normally.

Also - if you really want best compression, don't use gzip. Use lzma or 7z.

And when using gzip (which is good idea for various of reasons anyway) consider using `pigz` program and not the `gzip`.

Comment: pigz is "parallel gzip" which uses all your cores for gzip compression. You can watch `top` and see it using anywhere between 200%-400$ CPU.

Comment: FYI, for .bz2 format, use: BZIP2=-9 tar cvjf file.tar.bz2 /path/to/directory

Comment: The environment variable seems to now be `GZIP_OPT`, the usage should be the same.

Comment: From the man page on Ubuntu 16.04 for gzip: "On Vax/VMS, the name of the environment variable is GZIP_OPT, to avoid a conflict with the symbol set for invocation of the program." For sh, csh, and MSDOS it should still just be GZIP

Comment: This is what I get when I try to set `GZIP` environment variable to `-9`: *gzip: warning: GZIP environment variable is deprecated; use an alias or script*

Comment: @patryk.beza see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46167772/with-gnu-gzip-environment-variable-deprecated-how-to-control-zlib-compression-v. It says that `-I 'gzip <args>'` is now the recommended way`.

Comment: @Tomofumi BZIP2=-9 is not necessary, because bzip2 already defaults to -9.

Answer (score 96):

Instead of using the gzip flag for tar, gzip the files manually after the tar process, then you can specify the compression level for the gzip program:

```
tar -cvf files.tar /path/to/file0 /path/to/file1 ; gzip -9 files.tar
```

Or you could use:

```
tar cvf - /path/to/file0 /path/to/file1 | gzip -9 - > files.tar.gz
```

The -9 in the gzip command line tells gzip to use the maximum possible compression level (default is -6).

**Edit:** Fixed pipe command line based on @depesz comment.

Comment: Using pipes should be done with: `tar cvf - /path/to/directory | gzip -9 - > file.tar.gz`

Comment: 1st example should end with `file.tar`, since `gzip` adds the ".gz" extension.

Comment: why don't you skip `f -`? if there is no file, then it is stdin/out

Comment: addition to the previos comment. From "man tar" section Environtment: TAPE    Device or file to use for the archive if --file is not specified.  If this environment variable is unset, use stdin or stdout instead.

Comment: and we can reduce "gzip -9 -" -> "gzip -9". From "man gzip" section Description: If  no files are specified, or if a file name is "-", the standard input is compressed to the standard output.

Answer (score 83):

Modern versions of tar support the xz archive format (GNU tar, [since 1.22](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/#releases) in 2009, Busybox [since 1.17.0](http://www.busybox.net/news.html) in 2010).

It's based on [lzma2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Markov_chain_algorithm#LZMA2_format), kind of like a [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) version of [gz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip). This gives better compression if you are ok with the requirement of needing xz support.

```
tar -Jcvf file.tar.xz /path/to/directory
```

I just found out [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28976/how-to-xz-a-directory-with-tar-using-maximum-compression) (basically a dupe of this question, but in the Unix stackexchange) that there is also a XZ_OPT=-9 environment variable to control the XZ compression level similar to the GZIP one in the other post.

```
XZ_OPT=-9 tar -Jcvf file.tar.xz /path/to/directory
```

Comment: +1 xz is far better than both bzip2 and gzip.  Here's a comparison:  http://tukaani.org/lzma/benchmarks.html

Comment: The trade-off is speed. XZ is *significantly* slower.

Comment: no. xz -1 *significantly* beats bz2 -1~9 in terms of both compression ratio, compression/decompression speed. bz2 is the most awful format among popular formats. In short, if you ever use bz2, try xz -1, that's done.

Comment: @YumeYao FYI this is not always true, I just tried to compress some data with both bzip2 and xz at -9 compression level, xz gives me a 38M compressed size whereas bzip2 gives me 36M.

Comment: all boils down to type of data that you need to compress I thing - not reversed :)

Answer (score 44):

```
tar cv /path/to/directory | gzip --best > file.tar.gz
```

This is Matrix Mole's second solution, but slightly shortened:

When calling tar, option `f` states that the output is a file. Setting it to `-` (stdout) makes tar write its output to stdout which is the default behavior without both `f` and `-`.

And as stated by the `gzip` man page, if no files are specified gzip will compress from standard input. There is no need for `-` in the `gzip` call.

Option `--best` (equivalent to `-9`) sets the highest compression level.

Comment: This works beautifully.  Also if you run as root, permissions & owners are preserved too. Otherwise you must specify.  Also if it wasn't obvious "-9" is best compression and "-1" is fastest compression.  "-1" still takes a looong time if you have lots of files ;-)

Comment: This works with `xz` and `pixz` too. It is a great way to control the number of threads used for parallel compressing without having to create an intermediate .tar file. Like so `tar -cv /path/to/dir | pixz -p4 > output.tpxz`

Answer (score 25):

There is also the option to specify the compression program using `-I`.  This can include the compression level option.

```
tar -I 'gzip -9' -cvf file.tar.gz /path/to/directory
```

Note that the `-I` option is shorthand for `--use-compress-program=COMMAND`. This is important if you're not using [GNU `tar`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html) but [BSD `tar`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdtar&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+5.3-stable).
The latter uses the `-I` option as shorthand for the `--files-from filename` option.

So to be make your command "cross-platform" you could write:

```
tar --use-compress-program='gzip -9' -cvf file.tar.gz /path/to/directory
```

Comment: Older versions of tar such as that provided in CentOS 6 & 7 do not support providing arguments in the `-I` arg, they will try to treat the whole thing as a program name to exec, and thus fail.  At least as of tar 1.29 in Debian Stretch, this does work.

Comment: @Cheetah which version of tar?

Comment: @Cheetah I can confirm that it doesn't work for tar v1.26 in CentOS 7.x, returns this error : `tar (child): gzip -9: Cannot exec: No such file or directory`

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari "Cannot exec: No such file or directory" that probably means you need to specify the full gzip file name `tar -I '/bin/gzip -9' -cvf file.tar.gz /path/to/directory`.

Comment: @RonJohn no, sadly it's due to the old version of tar.  `'gzip'` works, `'/bin/gzip'` works, `'/bin/gzip -9'` doesn't.

Answer (score 17):

And of course macOS bsd-derived tar has to be different:

```
tar -czf file.tar.gz --options gzip:compression-level=9 /path/to/directory
```

Comment: however `--use-compress-program` works there too, so I'd use that for portability