# Zip/gzip compression ratio much less in Linux than in Windows

Tags: windows, linux, compression, zip, gzip

I have a bunch of very huge files located on a ***Linux*** machine that I would like to compress and save some space. I have tried using the *tar/gzip* combination and I have noticed that the compression ratio is not very good. A `1.2GB` file was compressed into a `1.1GB` file. I have tried increasing the compression level as suggested here: [How to specify level of compression when using tar -zcvf?](https://superuser.com/questions/305128/how-to-specify-level-of-compression-when-using-tar-zcvf)

but it still wasn't any better. I've copied the same file to a ***Windows*** machine and ran WinRar on it. The resulting compressed file was only `0.45GB` in size.

Is there a reason for such a huge discrepancy? Is there a better compressing tool for Linux?

**UPDATE:** I've even tried lzma and still not much better

Comment: uh, as explained below..., you're comparing apples to oranges...  rar is not zip, nor are either of those gzip.  Try compressing with the SAME method to compare things.   RAR is newer and uses different techniques to compress data.  (There's also stuffit, Z, xz, arc, arj, sea, *yes, I'm old*)   `There IS a rar utility for linux`, package name usually 'rar'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gzip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) is not a very good algorithm compared to [Rar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rar).

A more common method for linux these days is [bzip2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip) which is installed by default on almost all linux distributions.

You can switch the `tar` archiver to use bzip2 compression by changing your command line to `tar -cvjf` rather than `tar -cvzf` the key being the replacement of the `z` with `j` in the options.

This should hopefully yield a good increase in compression ratio.

The reason for the discrepancy is because they are fundamentally different algorithms for compression.  Gzip is an older algorithm and older algorithms tend to be less computationally intensive so that they would finish in a reasonable time.  This is an effect of more readily available processing power, better and more computationally intensive algorithms can be used that finish in a similar time than an older algorithm did on an older computer.  Conversely the older algorithms will complete compression much faster on a newer computer.

Almost any Windows archiver has an equivalent on Linux.  [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) is a nice archiver that gets good results on Windows and has an unofficial Linux version.

Comment: `bzip2` is a bit dated these days. Try `xz` instead.